# PDF file extension format

Tags: pdf

Since upgrading CiviCRM to 5.46.3 When trying Print/merge document it does not download as a .pdf extension. The file can be opened on MacOS or Linux machines but doesn't open on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the CiviCRM core issue and has been resolved in a recent version.

Either you can upgrade CiviCRM to 5.49.1 or apply the below patches to fix the issue.

- https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/22532.patch
- https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23083.patch